# Como puedo validar datos desde Login.class.php?

Tags: php

Buen día... quisiera que me ayudaran. Tengo un **validar.php**, ahí es donde entra mi **login** y valida los datos que existen dentro del arreglo, pero necesito que ese código este ahora en **Logn.class.php** y no se como ponerlo. La verdad soy nueva en php...

**validar.php**

`<?php`

```
$obteneruser = $_POST['Nombre']; 
$obtenerpass = $_POST['Pass']; 

$user= array(); 
$user[0]='murillo'; 
$user[1]='cris';
$usersize=count($user); 

$password= array(); 
$password[0]='abc123'; 
$password[1]='redes2018'; 

$existe=0; 
if ((isset($obteneruser)) && (isset($obtenerpass))){    
for ($i=0;$i<$usersize;$i++){       
    if($user[$i]==$obteneruser){
         if($password[$i]==$obtenerpass){
            $existe=1;
        }
       break;
   }
 } 
    if ($existe) 
      echo "Usuario y Contraseña CORRECTOS</b>"; 
    else 
      echo "Usuario y Contraseña INCORRECTOS</b>"; 
}
```

***Login.class.php***

```
<?php
class Login extends WSBase{

    protected function _request($action,$data){

        switch($action){
            case 1://Create
                            $this->_accederLogin($data["Nombre"], $data["Pass"]);


                break;
                        case 2:
                          $this->_validarLogin($data["Nombre"], $data["Pass"]);

            default:
                //Error: Undefined Request          
        }

        }   
        public function _accederLogin ($Nombre, $Pass){
           $this->Nombre = $Nombre;
           $this->Pass = $Pass;
        }
        public function _validarLogin ($Nombre, $Pass){



        }
}
?>
```

Comment: podrias ser un poco mas claro no entiendo lo que deseas :v

Answer (score 0):

En tu archivo **validar.php** debes incluir la clase que vas a utilizar, luego creas un objeto de la clase que realizara las acciones y por último ejecutas el request así:

```
<php?

require_once ('Logn.class.php');
$logueo = new Login();//Creas un objeto de tipo login

$logueo->_request($accion, $data);//realizas la peticion a la clase
//en $accion pasas lo que deseas realizar: crear , validar; y en $data pasas el array con los datos
<?
```

Saludos

Comment: Te ha servido la respuesta o sigues presentando problemas?